# Compiling with mpifort produces error: "I don't understand 'm' flag!"

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, mpi

I recently installed openmpi on my macbook (High Sierra 10.13.6). In the process, I was also forced to do a fresh install of gcc and then openmpi using homebrew. Now, when I try to compile a simple "Hello World" program using the command mpifort Hello.f90 from the terminal, I get the following error:

FATAL:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!

I see others with similar issues, though not related to openmpi. I know it has something to do with assembler. Nothing suggested worked for me :(

One more potential clue: I have been having soooo many problems with compiling gcc and gfortran ever since my OS updated...

Comment: did you update xcode as well?

Comment: Thanks Gilles, looks like that was indeed the issue, though updating it was tricky. In the end, I decided to just upgrade my OS to catalina and reinstall everything. It works now, but is surprisingly slow :(  Thanks again!